# Discord.js not recognizing file path as directory

Tags: discord.js

I am trying to learn how to use the / command system in Discord.js, however, following the Discord.js guide results in the following error:

`Error: ENOTDIR: not a directory, scandir`
on line:
`deploy-commands.js:14:26`
(this is the const commandFiles line)
This is with the code directly from the guide site:

```
const commands = [];
// Grab all the command files from the commands directory you created earlier
const foldersPath = path.join(__dirname, 'commands');
const commandFolders = fs.readdirSync(foldersPath);

for (const folder of commandFolders) {
    // Grab all the command files from the commands directory you created earlier
    const commandsPath = path.join(foldersPath, folder);
    const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(commandsPath).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
    // Grab the SlashCommandBuilder#toJSON() output of each command's data for deployment
    for (const file of commandFiles) {
        const filePath = path.join(commandsPath, file);
        const command = require(filePath);
        if ('data' in command && 'execute' in command) {
            commands.push(command.data.toJSON());
        } else {
            console.log(`[WARNING] The command at ${filePath} is missing a required "data" or "execute" property.`);
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried altering the code in a few ways, some of which allow me to launch the bot, but it does not execute the / commands when they are used.

My bot will display the command, but when I use the / command, the bot will not actually run my command file.

guide site: [text](https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/command-deployment.html#guild-commands)

Answer (score 0):

Deploy commands is meant to register the commands to guilds. You also need to register the commands to your bot client in your main script (like `index.js`) before you do `client.login(token)`.

Normally you would want to fetch all scripts from one folder like the example provided by the [DiscordJS guide](https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/command-handling.html#loading-command-files)

I take it a bit further and also look into sub folders so keep that in mind while looking at this example on how to register commands:

```js
// index.js
const fs = require('node:fs');

// Get command files
function getCommandFiles(client, dir) {
    const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./' + dir);
    for (const file of commandFiles) {
        if (file.endsWith('.js')) {
            registerCommand(client, dir, file);
        }
        // Check if the file is a folder
        else if (file.match(/[a-zA-Z0-9 -_]+/i)) { 
            // Skip the archive folder
            if (file == 'Archive') { continue; } 
            getCommandFiles(client, dir + '/' + file);
        }
    }
}
// Register the command files to the client
function registerCommand(client, dir, file) {
    const command = require(`../${dir}/${file}`);
    // Set a new item in the Collection
    // With the key as the command name and the value as the exported module
    client.commands.set(command.data.name, command);
    console.log(`Registering Command: ${command.data.name} - ${file}`);
}

// Start command registration
getCommandFiles(client, 'commands');
```

Also keep in mind that this is just the relevant part of the `index.js` script and not everything needed to get the bot running. If you are unsure about what the `index.js` should look like, take a look at the [DiscordJS set-up guide](https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/main-file.html#running-your-application)

For reference; my folder structure could look something like this:

```
commands\
|- ping.js
|- fun\
|- |- funCommand.js
index.js
deployCommands.js
```